# Should I have the most recent Ubuntu on an old laptop?

Tags: software-installation

I have been given an old Celeron laptop (I have not the exact specs with me as I am at work), with the latest version of Ubuntu on it. I have just upgraded the memory to 2GB (that's the maximum the laptop can take), but the laptop is incredibly slow (kind of painful as even typing takes ages to appear on the screen).

Am I better off replacing Ubuntu with an earlier version?

Answer (score 2):

Get [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) instead of the "vanilla" version of Ubuntu. Preferably the 14.04 LTS version. Lubuntu takes smoothness to the extreme but does not have a lot of eye candy. Xubuntu is very lightweight too but is usually more customizable.

Comment: I've tried Xubuntu and Lubuntu on more than a dozen old XP machines, and is Lubuntu is my choice. You won't have lots of eye candy, but it will work.

Comment: I prefer Xubuntu for my daily use (had a dual boot, deleted Windows after getting Xubuntu 14.04). It is jus as smooth as Lubuntu (uses like extra 30 MBs of ram) and I can customize it the way I want (to look like almost any DE out there).

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, thanks very much, I will try Xubuntu and let you know how i get on
J

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu and Xubuntu is what you are looking for, Unity (ubuntu ui) might be really heavy for old computers.